# Запуск сервера node на другом html

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Размещаю server.js в папке projects, внутри этой папки лежит папка src.
При запуске node server.js этот конфиг использует index.html которая лежит в папке projects, как сделать так что бы при запуске node server.js запускался html который лежит в папке src?

**server.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const WebpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");

const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
});

server.listen(3000, "localhost", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("Listening at http://localhost:3000/");
    return 0;
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "eval",
    entry: {
        Application: [
            "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000",
            "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
            "./src/Scripts/index"
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "src", "Build"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: path.join("src", "Build")
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ["react-hot", "babel"],
            include: path.join(__dirname, "src")
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Переписать `.webpack.config` (который вы не считаете нужным приводить), очевидно.

Comment: Добавил webpack config

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы все запросы переправлялись в src как-то так:

```
const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: __dirname + '/sec'
});
```